# How to check if resouce was allocated correctly in a python ContextDecorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, with-statement, contextmanager

I have a class

```
class Resource:
    __init__(self):
        self.resource = ...
    __enter__(self):
        #can fail, such as file open returning error, memory allocation fail, or any more complicated failure
    __exit__(self,*args):
        ...
```

Now I want

```
with Resource() as r:
    r.do_stuff()
```

But if `r` has failed to `__enter__()` successfully, this fails.

What is the correct, pythonic way of handling this?

I didn't want to use some `is_allocated_correctly`

like so

```
with Resource() as r:
    if r.is_allocated_correctly():
        r.do_stuff()
```

as it breaks the point of the with statement.

Please give me some idea what to do here.

Comment: assuming the resource is allocated either in the `__init__` or `__enter__` AND an allocation failure would raise an exception (which is what should happen for any not-totally-broken lib allocating resources of any kind) AND you don't do anything stupid (like silently swallowing this exception) in your  `Resource` class, then you will NEVER enter the `with` block if the resource is not "correctly allocated". IOW, you have nothing special to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `with` statement is correctly de-allocate resources or reset state after the block has finished.

If you can't enter the context block without an error, that needs handling outside of the with statement.

Surround the whole thing with a `try/except`:

```
try:
    with Resource() as r:
        r.do_stuff()
except ResourceException as error:
    handle_error(error)
```

Or if there's nothing you can do about the error, just let it pass:

```
with Resource() as r:
    r.do_stuff()
```